# Why am I often timing out connecting to S3 from zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-s3

I have what I would consider very simple code to connect to amazon S3 and empty a bucket.

```
$s3 = new Zend_Service_Amazon_S3(
      "accessKey",
      "secretKey");
$s3->cleanBucket("my.bucket");
```

And 9 times out of 10 I get:

```
Message: Unable to Connect to tcp://my.bucket.s3.amazonaws.com:80. Error #0: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
```

I am working from localhost in wamp if that changes anything (and it probably does). Our connection is stable so I doubt I lose internet that often.

It does work from time to time with nothing changed in my code so that makes me think something else is wrong but as far as I know amazon is not known for being down all the time. For what its worth in Yii framework it never does that so it might be a bug in Zend.

Anyways if anyone has tips or a solution to this problem.

Comment: "getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known" is pretty explicit.  PHP is unable to resolve DNS for the host in question.  Check your DNS services?

Comment: @Charles yets sometimes it works? And from the same pc on another project using Yii framework we never encounter this problem. Or when doing a get request also.

Comment: I'll try to flush dns and retry who knows you might be right.

Comment: It could also be that ZF's doing something *weird*.  I mean, it's opening a freaking TCP connection, which implies that they're doing their own HTTP *by hand*, which is silly.  Have you considered using the official Amazon PHP SDK here?  It's even weirder, but it at least uses sane techniques under the hood...

Comment: @Charles well now I do consider it but am quite short on time. I'll to upload the code to some server and see if it helps. We have a complicated network setup here and its possible the proxy or whatever is interfering.